# How to add unit test for a function that calls a function received in props

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

```
 onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const errors = this.validateForm()
   if (!errors) {
     const { handleSubmit } = this.props
     handleSubmit(e)
   }
 }

 <---------- unit test ---------> 

 it('calls onSubmit prop function when form is submitted', () => {
   const onSubmit = jest.fn()
   const handleSubmit = jest.fn()
   const wrapper1 = mount(<Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} onSubmit= 
   {onSubmit} />)
   const form = wrapper1.find('form')
   form.simulate('submit')
   expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
 })

 <----------- HTML ----------->

 <Form
  onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
  render={() => (
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} id="submit-form">
      <div>
        <label>{countryName}</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="submit-form" className="invisible" />    
    </form>
  )}
/>
```

Above code snippet is the example of the HTML being rendered and `onSubmit` is the function that is being called when user submits the form. 
Basically, this component is generic form component thus `handleSubmit` is  sent from the parent component in props and with the unit test that I have added it generates the error `Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.` 
And if I remove handleSubmit as:

```
it('calls onSubmit prop function when form is submitted', () => {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn()
  const wrapper1 = mount(<Form onSubmit= 
  {onSubmit} />)
  const form = wrapper1.find('form')
  form.simulate('submit')
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

it generates `TypeError: handleSubmit is not a function` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in test you are checking `onSubmit` which is not used at all inside the component:

```
it('calls onSubmit prop function when form is submitted', () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn() //not used in the component
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn()
    const wrapper1 = mount(<Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} onSubmit={onSubmit} />)
    const form = wrapper1.find('form')
    form.simulate('submit')
    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) //In component you don't use onSubmit
})
```

You should test usage of `handleSubmit`:

```
it('calls onSubmit prop function when form is submitted', () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn()
    const wrapper1 = mount(<Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>)
    const form = wrapper1.find('form')
    form.simulate('submit')
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Comment: I'm passing `handleSubmit` in prop as you may see `const wrapper1 = mount(<Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} onSubmit= 
   {onSubmit} />)`

Comment: Where do you define `onSubmit` function? Inside `Form` component or outside? If outside of the `Form` component it will not read `handleSubmit` prop from it.

Comment: it is defined inside form component !

Comment: Can you share your component code as I'm not sure how it is structured?

Comment: @fahadtufail I've updated the answer. It should solve this issue. If it does please mark as resolved.

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't get your point that `onSubmit` didnt used in component. :/

Comment: In the component code it uses : `this.onSubmit` which means that this is not something you provide as a props so passing that prop to the form doesn't have sense. If the answer solves your issue please mark it.